# Why we use Reset Layout to Standard Value?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

In template, I have a parent template named:

> BasePage

I added 2 sublayouts to BasePage template

> sublayout1, sublayout2

I created a template (ChildPage template) that inherit from BasePage template. Now the ChildPage template also have 2 sublayouts via Standard Value. When I added **sublayout3** to BasePage template WHY ChildPage template doesn't update ? 
I have to use Reset Layout to Standard Value it was updated.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, there have been similar ones raised, I would raise it with Sitecore.

Comment: @jammykam, I and my team also think it is bug. Please raise it to Sitecore. Thanks

Comment: What version of Sitecore you're using?

Comment: @MarvinGlennLacuna, Sitecore 8.0 Update 6

Comment: Re-reading your question, this is a known bug. **You** need to contact Sitecore Support, it's similar (but not the same it seems) as this [Issues with inheriting presentation details from base templates](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/649914)

Comment: I found that after I use the function "Copy and edit the layout from the Standard Value item (if any) to this item" it happen.

Comment: @jammykam  - Can we Reset (ChildPage template) _standard values? Nothing happens to me when I tried

Answer (score 1):

Just please do correct me if my understanding to your question is incorrect.

So..

You have a base template and this base template has 2 controls (sublayout).

You also have page template (child page) that has 2 controls (sublayout), as well. The page template inherits to the base template which has (2 controls)

So you have like this:

> Base template (2 controls)
>
> Page template (2 controls)

Then you added another control to the Base template, so the Base Template has 3 controls now.

> Base Template (3 controls)

And your expectation is by adding a rendering control in the Base template, the changes will get cascaded in its implementer in your case, the page template?

If so, then, as from what I understand about inheritance, if the *Standard Value* of the page template (implementer) was not yet touched, meaning you didn't edit the presentation details. The changes from the base template rendering controls will be automatically cascaded to the *page template*. Otherwise, as from what you have experienced. It didn't reflected and therefore you were forced to reset the layout. After resetting the layout, and add another rendering control to the base template it will cascade automatically again.

I simulated your issue in a fresh installed v.8.1-U2 and I got the same experience, though, this is different from your current version. I hope you were also able to simulate it on your end.

If the problem still persist, after trying the above steps I did, then you probably might want to contact Sitecore support. But before doing that, try to recreate the issue on the fresh installed Sitecore instance. Thanks.

Comment: I doesn't mentioned FIELD in this case, 3 controls are difference. I have Base template (2 controls) , I created Page template inherit Base Template and Page template now have 2 controls via Standard Value. I expect that when I add controls to Base template, Page template will be updated (3 controls).

Comment: @KenNguyen I updated my answer. I also able to replicate the issue just now and I found the root cause. Please see above explanation.

Comment: yes, I expect that it will be changed on the page template.

Comment: @KenNguyen That makes sense, because you don't want your changes to the page template get overwritten by the changes in the base template since it was intentionally edited. I think this is the same on how the cloning field relationship works. If you clone an item (CLONE ABC) and you edited the clone field, say Title, then any field changes on the Title of the original item will not cascaded on the CLONE ABC Title field not unless you reset it as well. Hope this answers your concern. Thanks.